# How to deploy a mvc4 website connect a existing database in visual studio 2010?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a mvc4 website with connecting a database. The database is also use by another application. So, I don't recreate the database when I deploy the mvc4 website.

connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Qcgl.csdl|res://*/Models.Qcgl.ssdl|res://*/Models.Qcgl.msl;
 provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="
 data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;
 attachdbfilename=D:\xxx.mdf;integrated security=True;
 connect timeout=30;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework""

The error is

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file xxx.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework codefirst approach ?

Comment: No, I used a existing database to create a model.

Answer (score 0):

Try below connection string

```
<add name="ContextName" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YorUserid;Password=YourPassword Trusted_Connection=yes;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;multipleactiveresultsets=True;
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```